# Why does `Task<C, Error>` work even though `C` is a class which is not `Sendable`, or is it?

Tags: swift, async-await

Consider this code snippet:

```
class C1 {
    var i: Int
    init(i: Int) { self.i = i }
}
let t4 = Task<C1, Error>(operation: { return C1(i: 1) })
let v4: C1 = try await t4.value
```

`Task` is defined as:

```
@frozen public struct Task<Success, Failure> : Sendable where Success : Sendable, Failure : Error {
}
```

`Sendable`s documentation says:

```
/// ### Sendable Classes
///
/// To satisfy the requirements of the `Sendable` protocol,
/// a class must:
///
/// - Be marked `final`
///
/// - Contain only stored properties that are immutable and sendable
///
/// - Have no superclass or have `NSObject` as the superclass
```

`C1` is not final, hence I'd assume, that it is not `Sendable`.

So why does the `Task` snippet work? What am I missing?
(Tried this in Xcode 14.1 <del>14.2</del>)

---

EDIT #2:
(Removed further details - It is all covered by loremipsum's answer.)

Comment: Unless you have strict concurrency enforced you may or may not get a warning. I don’t think warning will be enabled until Swift 6.

Comment: @loremipsum Yep - you're right. If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Rob Sure - I agree; let's wait a bit for loremipsum and if nothing happens, I'll adjust things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C1` is not `Sendable` right now. Apple is allowing developers to catch these things little by little.

Strict Concurrency Checking is set to `minimal` by default, you can set to targeted or complete if you want to get Sendable related warnings

> Discussion

> **Minimal**: Enforce Sendable constraints only where it has been explicitly adopted and perform actor-isolation checking wherever code has adopted concurrency.

> **Targeted**: Enforce Sendable constraints and perform actor-isolation checking wherever code has adopted concurrency, including code that has explicitly adopted Sendable.

> **Complete**: Enforce Sendable constraints and actor-isolation checking throughout the entire module.Minimal: Enforce Sendable constraints only where it has been explicitly adopted and perform actor-isolation checking wherever code has adopted concurrency.
> Targeted: Enforce Sendable constraints and perform actor-isolation checking wherever code has adopted concurrency, including code that has explicitly adopted Sendable.
> Complete: Enforce Sendable constraints and actor-isolation checking throughout the entire module.

The setting for this is in the `Build Settings > Swift Compiler Language > Strict Concurrency Checking`

Apple says that "***Sendable conformance and other Sendable-related problems -- will be presented as warnings in Swift 5, not errors, to make it easier to work through the problems one by one***".

You can hear more about it in the [WWDC video Eliminate Data Races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/110351) video from about 24:20 on.