# How to rewrite Firebase Remote Config closure-based code to async/await version

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, firebase-remote-config

I need to rewrite my old closure-based code that accesses remote configs in firebase to its async await version. I am new to SwiftUI async/await. So I have:

```
final class RemoteConfigService {

    private let isDebugEnabled: Bool
    private let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
    private let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

    init(isDebugEnabled: Bool) {
        self.isDebugEnabled = isDebugEnabled
    }

    func fetch(
        defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile,
        expirationDuration: TimeInterval,
        onComplete: @escaping (RemoteConfig) -> Void,
        onError: @escaping (Error?) -> Void
    ) {
        concurrentQueue.async { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            
            strongSelf.semaphore.wait()

            let expirationDuration = !strongSelf.isDebugEnabled ? expirationDuration : 0
            let defaultValues = defaultValuesPlistFile.plist?.dictionary as? [String: NSObject]
            let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
            remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultValues)
            remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration) { [remoteConfig] status, error in
                strongSelf.semaphore.signal()
                
                if status == .success || status == .throttled {
                    remoteConfig.activate { _, _ in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            onComplete(remoteConfig)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        onError(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As I can see Xcode generated async versions of methods for closure based in FirebaseRemoteConfig automatically. I can use them

However here I my problems

1. I've used semaphores to synchronize access to this RemoteConfig (I don't remember why it was needed but I would like to keep it safe in async await version)
2. There is background queue, so this configs are fetched in background. How to execute async code in background
3. Results are returned on main thread using DispatchQueue.main.async

I've tried to write it and achived something like this but I think that i missed semaphores and synchronizations and I am not sure that code is executed in the background and I am almos sure it doesn't return results on main thread.

```
func fetch(defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile, expirationDuration: TimeInterval) async throws -> RemoteConfig {
        try await Task.detached(priority: .background) { [isDebugEnabled] in
            let expirationDuration = !isDebugEnabled ? expirationDuration : 0
            let defaultValues = defaultValuesPlistFile.plist?.dictionary as? [String: NSObject]
            let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
            remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultValues)
            
            let status = try await remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration)
            
            guard status == .success || status == .throttled else {
                throw FeatureStatusError.unsupported
            }
            
            _ = try await remoteConfig.activate()
            
            return remoteConfig
        }.value
    }
```

**UPDATE**
My second thought is to add actor

```
actor RemoteConfigService {
    
    let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    
    private let isDebugEnabled: Bool
    
    init(isDebugEnabled: Bool) {
        self.isDebugEnabled = isDebugEnabled
    }
    
    func fetch(defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile, expirationDuration: TimeInterval) async throws -> RemoteConfig {
        
        let expirationDuration = !isDebugEnabled ? expirationDuration : 0
        let defaultValues = defaultValuesPlistFile.plist?.dictionary as? [String: NSObject]
        
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultValues)
        
        let status = try await remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration)
        
        guard status == .success || status == .throttled else {
            throw FeatureStatusError.unsupported
        }
        
        _ = try await remoteConfig.activate()
        
        return remoteConfig
    }
}
```

and for backward compatibility for closure-based code doing extension like this with non isolated

```
extension RemoteConfigService {
    nonisolated func fetch(
        defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile,
        expirationDuration: TimeInterval,
        onComplete: @escaping (RemoteConfig) -> Void,
        onError: @escaping (Error?) -> Void
    ) {
        Task {
            do {
                let remoteConfig = try await fetch(defaultValuesPlistFile: defaultValuesPlistFile, expirationDuration: expirationDuration)
                
                await MainActor.run {
                    onComplete(remoteConfig)
                }
            } catch {
                await MainActor.run {
                    onError(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
final actor RemoteConfigService {
    
    let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    
    private let isDebugEnabled: Bool
    private let expirationDuration: TimeInterval
    
    init(isDebugEnabled: Bool, defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile, expirationDuration: TimeInterval) {
        self.isDebugEnabled = isDebugEnabled
        self.expirationDuration = expirationDuration
        
        let defaultValues = defaultValuesPlistFile.plist?.dictionary as? [String: NSObject]
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultValues)
    }
    
    func fetch() async throws -> RemoteConfig {
        let expirationDuration = !isDebugEnabled ? expirationDuration : 0
        let status = try await remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration)
        
        guard status == .success || status == .throttled else {
            throw FeatureStatusError.unsupported
        }
        
        _ = try await remoteConfig.activate()
        
        return remoteConfig
    }
}
```

Comment: Semaphore and async await are not compatible. Are these async methods provided by Firebase or did you create them? If they are provided your code is fine they get detached from the original actor and returned to their original actor. Concurrency doesn’t deal with threads it deals with actors.

Comment: I suppose that Firebase framework is written in Objective-C and there is something like automatic generation of async methods Concurrency Ineropability? https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md

Comment: I whink this semaphores where important as I can have multiple calls to this fatch method and they can be race condition (at least in closure-based code) when doing this setDefaults() and fetch() it probably caused some crashes or warnings. 
So I consider if I shouldn't create here actor for RemoteConfigService and make remoteConfig as property of this actor isolated by it. I've added my second approach to this rewrite

Comment: Firebase has been slowly adding async await methods, I just haven’t looked at the library myself that is why I added the caveat. If they were there with auto completion and you didn’t create them the methods would be fine.

Comment: Yes, use actor if you are going full concurrency, data races are still possible with concurrency but much less likely, a sure way of creating them is by mixing semaphores, dispatchqueues, etc with async await.

Comment: You can turn on concurrency checking too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709573/why-does-taskc-error-work-even-though-c-is-a-class-which-is-not-sendable/75713017#75713017 it isn’t perfect yet but it is progressing.

Comment: Don’t leave floating Tasks like that last set of code and then mix in completion handlers, that is creating a leak and you are going backwards. Once you start adopting async await stick with it all the way. Completion handlers are the past.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10132

Comment: But I cannot rewrite all the code in my code base at once. this Task in extension will be causing some troubles? I've found this solution in this article https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/async-await-combine-closures/

Comment: That floating Task is a leak, you lose control of the task and essentially defeat the safety of an actor, you are making the method as nonisolated anyway so that may not be important in your case. Start by creating alternate methods, you dont have to replace everything at once just one chain of functions at a time. Converting from closures to async await only takes a few lines of code. Creating alternates is very easy just look at the video I linked above.

Comment: In your update 2, you are subject to actor reentrancy. Furthermore, `RemoteConfig` is not `Sendable`. (Turn on strict concurrency checking, and the compiler will warn you of this fact.)

Comment: Also, you do not need `final` in conjunction with `actor`.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> 1. I've used semaphores to synchronize access to this `RemoteConfig` (I don’t remember why it was needed but I would like to keep it safe in async await version)

The semaphore is being used to prevent concurrent requests. I do not see any formal warnings in the documentation prohibiting concurrent requests, but this is not an unreasonable pattern. (Why you would need to call this concurrently is the more interesting question.)

Unfortunately, semaphores with a serial queue are inefficient (tying up one of the very limited number of worker threads). Semaphores with a concurrent queue are even more problematic (it is possible to complete exhaust the worker thread pool with all sorts of unintended consequences). One could refactor this code to minimize the risk, but, given that you’re retiring this, anyway, I won’t belabor that point.

Simply note that one should try to avoid the whole semaphore anti-pattern.

You also said:

> 2. There is background queue, so this configs are fetched in background.

The `fetch` of the configuration is already asynchronous. That is not the purpose of the background queue. The background queue was only necessary because this routine used semaphores to block a thread (as you would never want to block the main thread). So, a detached task is not needed/desired.

---

The docs suggest that one should call `fetch` once (eliminating the need for the Swift concurrency equivalent of the semaphore trick to prevent concurrent access) and then set up a listener for updates (which, in Swift concurrency, would be an `AsyncSequence`, namely an `AsyncStream`).

So, perhaps:

```swift
actor RemoteConfigService {
    private let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    private let expirationDuration: TimeInterval
    private let isDebugEnabled: Bool

    init(isDebugEnabled: Bool, defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile, expirationDuration: TimeInterval) {
        self.isDebugEnabled = isDebugEnabled
        self.expirationDuration = !isDebugEnabled ? expirationDuration : 0

        let defaultValues = defaultValuesPlistFile.plist?.dictionary as? [String: NSObject]
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultValues)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func fetch() async throws -> Bool {
        let status = try await remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration)

        guard status == .success || status == .throttled else {
            throw FeatureStatusError.unsupported
        }

        return try await remoteConfig.activate()
    }

    func updatedKeys() -> AsyncStream<Set<String>> {
        AsyncStream<Set<String>> { continuation in
            remoteConfig.addOnConfigUpdateListener { update, error in
                guard let update, error == nil else {
                    logger.error("\(error ?? FeatureStatusError.unknown)")
                    return
                }

                continuation.yield(update.updatedKeys)
            }

            continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                logger.debug("RemoteConfigService.configurations terminated")

                // generally I would remove this listener here, but I don't see an API for that;
                // that having been said, you probably would set this up once and never terminate, so perhaps that is moot
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the caller can monitor these updates:

```swift
func handleConfigurationUpdates() async {
    for await keys in await remoteConfigService.updatedKeys() {
        // presumably do something with the updated keys
    }
}
```

That having been said, if refactoring your code as advised in the documents is too difficult, and you *really* want to repeatedly `fetch` but prevent concurrent tasks, the elegant solution would be to use an [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md). Or, keeping it simple, you can just `await` the previous task. E.g.,

```swift
actor RemoteConfigService {
    private let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
    private let expirationDuration: TimeInterval
    private let isDebugEnabled: Bool
    private var previousTask: Task<Bool, Error>?


    init(isDebugEnabled: Bool, defaultValuesPlistFile: PlistFile, expirationDuration: TimeInterval) {
        self.isDebugEnabled = isDebugEnabled
        self.expirationDuration = !isDebugEnabled ? expirationDuration : 0

        let defaultValues = defaultValuesPlistFile.plist?.dictionary as? [String: NSObject]
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultValues)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func fetch() async throws -> Bool {
        let task = Task { [previousTask] in
            _ = try await previousTask?.value

            let status = try await remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration)

            guard status == .success || status == .throttled else {
                throw FeatureStatusError.unsupported
            }

            return try await remoteConfig.activate()
        }
        previousTask = task

        return try await task.value
    }
}
```

This only lets one `fetch` at a time, even allowing for [actor reentrancy](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy), while avoiding semaphores, blocking any worker threads, etc. But, then again, like the semaphore pattern, this solves the concurrent request problem by backlogging them. That seems like a suboptimal solution. (It begs questions about why might you have concurrent requests in the first place, how to mitigate that, and if this is really likely to happen, perhaps how you might throttle/debounce, etc.)

But, IMHO, that's moot, as the best pattern is to fetch once and then listen for updates, as advised in the documentation.

Comment: OK I take it. But I think if there really is reentrancy problem in this case. 
If I do fetch() function like in the first code snippet i.e. whitout using previous task and returning just remote config, will it cause any problem if 2 task tries to access this fetch methods to fetch latest remote config with current values of configurations in firebase? I take it that at suspension point on await remoteConfig.fetch() there will be renetrancy and before returning `return remoteConfig` other asynchornous request to firebase can return and remote config will be update, but this still be latest val

Comment: I've added this version under Update 2

Comment: Yes, if you really insist on calling `fetch` multiple times (against the specific documentation recommendation), then you’ll need to use the latter pattern.

Comment: Ok, we eventually decided to rewrite this from scratch and implement as you suggested with single call to fetch and update listener. But now I consider if there is any benefit of using `actor` instead of class for RemoteConfigService ?