# Crash on account creation, error and button code included

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I am getting the following error around 20% of the time I try to create an account:
Can someone please help me in diagnosing the issue please

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010

```
    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2820 objc_msgSend + 32
1  UIKitCore                      0x2004a4 -[UIViewController dealloc] + 772
2  UIKitCore                      0x1fe0cc -[UINavigationController dealloc] + 308
3  UIKitCore                      0x486bbc -[_UISplitViewControllerColumnContents .cxx_destruct] + 44
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x6e00 objc_destructInstance + 80
6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x104fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2a26c cow_cleanup + 168
8  CoreFoundation                 0x62538 -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 148
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x20a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x6e00 objc_destructInstance + 80
11 libobjc.A.dylib                0x104fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x20a4 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
13 libobjc.A.dylib                0x6e00 objc_destructInstance + 80
14 libobjc.A.dylib                0x104fc _objc_rootDealloc + 80
15 UIKitCore                      0x2008d8 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 124
16 UIKitCore                      0x2005dc -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1084
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0x21d4 AutoreleasePoolPage::releaseUntil(objc_object**) + 196
18 libobjc.A.dylib                0x5bdc objc_autoreleasePoolPop + 256
19 UIKitCore                      0x1a0444 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 92
20 UIKitCore                      0x1a0364 -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 168
21 UIKitCore                      0x1a0278 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 496
22 UIKitCore                      0x3eee4 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 108
23 UIKitCore                      0x4fd608 _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
24 UIKitCore                      0x64de00 _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
25 UIKitCore                      0xcb1944 schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144
26 UIKitCore                      0xcb0ea0 runloopSourceCallback + 92
27 CoreFoundation                 0xd3208 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
28 CoreFoundation                 0xdf864 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
29 CoreFoundation                 0x646c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
30 CoreFoundation                 0x7a1c4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
31 CoreFoundation                 0x7f4dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
32 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal + 164
33 UIKitCore                      0x39d37c -[UIApplication _run] + 888
34 UIKitCore                      0x39cfe0 UIApplicationMain + 340
35 SwiftUI                        0x1bc3d8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_895 + 2472
36 SwiftUI                        0x1229b0 block_copy_helper.1 + 496
37 SwiftUI                        0x10ca54 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_901 + 2752
38 AppName                   0x7844 main + 23 (AppName.swift:23)
39 ???                            0x1ab1b0dec (Missing)
```

I don't get this crash when I am running in the simulator only when I run trough Firestore App distribution.

Code of the button causing crash and the viewModels:

```
@StateObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel.CreateAccountViewModel
...
Button("Create Account", action: viewModel.submit)
```

AuthViewModel:

```
func makeCreateAccountViewModel() -> CreateAccountViewModel {
        return CreateAccountViewModel(action: authService.createAccount(name:email:password:))
    }

class CreateAccountViewModel: FormViewModel<(name: String, email: String, password: String)> {
        convenience init(action: @escaping Action) {
            self.init(initialValue: (name: "", email: "", password: ""), action: action)
        }
    }
```

FormViewModel:

```
@MainActor
@dynamicMemberLookup
class FormViewModel<Value>: ObservableObject {
    typealias Action = (Value) async throws -> Void
    
    @Published var value: Value
    @Published var error: Error?
    @Published var isWorking = false
    
    subscript<T>(dynamicMember keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Value, T>) -> T {
        get { value[keyPath: keyPath] }
        set { value[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue }
    }
    
    private let action: Action
    
    init(initialValue: Value, action: @escaping Action) {
        self.value = initialValue
        self.action = action
    }
    
    nonisolated func submit() {
        Task {
            await handleSubmit()
        }
    }
    
    private func handleSubmit() async {
        isWorking = true
        do {
            try await action(value)
        } catch {
            print("[FormViewModel] Cannot submit: \(error)")
            self.error = error
        }
        isWorking = false
    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
private let auth = Auth.auth()

func createAccount(email: String, password: String) async throws {
        let result = try await auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        try await result.user.updateProfile(\.displayName, to: email)
    }

private extension FirebaseAuth.User {
    func updateProfile<T>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<UserProfileChangeRequest, T>, to newValue: T) async throws {
        var profileChangeRequest = createProfileChangeRequest()
        profileChangeRequest[keyPath: keyPath] = newValue
        try await profileChangeRequest.commitChanges()
    }
}
```

Please ask any questions and if there is anything that needs to be added to make it clearer.

Thanks

Further edits:
After completing the suggestion from lorem ipsum I turned on "strict/complete concurrency"
This gives me the following "error" on this code:

```
func createAccount(email: String, password: String) async throws {
        let result = try await auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
        try await result.user.updateProfile(\.displayName, to: email)
    }
```

let result part:
Non-sendable type 'AuthDataResult' returned by call from main actor-isolated context to non-isolated instance method 'createUser(withEmail:password:)' cannot cross actor boundary
try await part:
Non-sendable type 'WritableKeyPath<UserProfileChangeRequest, String?>' exiting main actor-isolated context in call to non-isolated instance method 'updateProfile(_:to:)' cannot cross actor boundary

Does anyone have advice on fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that there is a threading/actor issue you are essentially nullifying the safety of async await with the non isolated floating task you have going on there. The task is likely dying before anything gets done and then you are trying to alter UI. But there is so much that isn’t included, SwiftUI is very strict in its implementation since we are dealing with struct instead of classes. You likely can’t reproduce this on simulator because of your specs. You need an older, slower, device with poor/slow connection.

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you have any suggestions for my steps forward?

Comment: tough to say that non isolated task is an issue but so could other things such as the public StateObject, they should always be private.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the MainActor wrapper is to keep UI updates on the main actor. You remove the safety by nonisolating and “leaking” the `Task`.

Try something like

```
@State private var isProcessing: Bool = false
```

And

```
            Button {
                //This can start/stop a task
                isProcessing.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Create Account")
                    .task(id: isProcessing) {
                        guard isProcessing else {
                            return
                        }
                        await viewModel.handleSubmit()
                        isProcessing = false
                    }

            }
```

This will allow you to "hold on" to the task in the spirit of concurrency.

I would also suggest turning on "strict/complete concurrency" or at the very least "targeted".

[Why does `Task<C, Error>` work even though `C` is a class which is not `Sendable`, or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75709573/why-does-taskc-error-work-even-though-c-is-a-class-which-is-not-sendable/75713017#75713017)

And add

```
-Xfrontend -warn-concurrency 
-Xfrontend -enable-actor-data-race-checks
```

To `Build Settings > Swift Compiler > Other Swift Flags`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've implemented this code. I made handleSubmit no longer private to access it. It made a difference to the frequency of the crashes but I am still getting the same crash happening ~10% of the time. I haven't implemented the second part, hold on

Comment: @Mech the second part will likely open a huge can of worms. But there is no way around it Swift 6 will be upon us eventually.

Comment: You're not wrong! I will try to work out which of the worms is important to fix the issue

Comment: I get the following issue for the Auth Service createAccount: 'Non-sendable type 'AuthDataResult' returned by call from main actor-isolated context to non-isolated instance method 'createUser(withEmail:password:)' cannot cross actor boundary' This may be the issue

Comment: With 'Non-sendable type 'WritableKeyPath<UserProfileChangeRequest, String?>' exiting main actor-isolated context in call to non-isolated instance method 'updateProfile(_:to:)' cannot cross actor boundary' also being called as an issue on createAccount

Comment: @Mech [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/sendable-protocol-closures/) is a good article with `Sendable` info, sometimes it can be solved with `await Task.detached{\* code here *\}.value` but it depends on so many things. For others you have to make sure the object is thread safe and then make it conform.